# Get the index of a multidimensional array with the value of a given string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array,

```
var arr = [["present",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["absent",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];

var arr2 = [["J",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["M",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];
```

And I want to get the `data[0]` of the array that have value of `"Mary"`.
So in my example, value that I will get is `"absent"`.

I want also to get the index of the array arr2 that have value of `"Josh"`.
So in my second array, value that I will get is 0.

If possible to use underscore js, we can use it.
I tried to use `_.contains()` but failed.
Also these array is used in knockout js.

Comment: if you just want to know key path of any JSON Object you can use 
http://www.jsonmaker.com Or now it is available in Chrome console also.
this might helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other way of doing this job could be as follows;

```js
var    a1 = [["present",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["absent",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]],
       a2 = [["J",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["M",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]],["S",["Sally","Sam","Sammy Davis"]]],
getStatus = (a,n) => a.find(e => e[1].indexOf(n) !== -1)[0],
 getIndex = (a,n) => a.findIndex(e => e[1].indexOf(n) !== -1);

console.log(getStatus(a1,"Mary"));
console.log(getIndex(a2,"Sammy Davis"));
```

Comment: I tried this (getIndex function) in some arrays but results are either -1 or 0.

Comment: @John Arellano Then either your sample doesn't reflect what exactly you want or you are doing something wrong like uppercase or lowercase mismatches. I 've just extended the above code to have names with "S" and searched for "Sammy Davis" and just got 2; which i believe to be correct.

Comment: How to handle this one (getStatus function) if undefined? I got an error a.find() is undefined.

Comment: @John Arellano What browser are you using..? Besides are you passing an array as the first argument to `getStatus()`..?

Comment: firefox. yes. I am using knockout js. so the array is "self.arrName()".

Answer (score 0):

If your data set isn't really huge you can store two map objects in memory to quickly access values. Note that this won't work for duplicate names.

The benefit of this approach is that you only have to loop through each array once. If you use any method based on `indexOf`, you'll loop through your data every time you retrieve a value.

```js
var arr = [["present",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["absent",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];
var arr2 = [["J",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["M",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];

var makeKeyMap = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(map, data) {
    data[1].forEach(function(key) {
      map[key] = data[0];
    });
    
    return map;
  }, {});
};

var makeIndexMap = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(map, data, index) {
    data[1].forEach(function(key) {
      map[key] = index;
    });
    
    return map;
  }, {});
};

var arrMap = makeKeyMap(arr);
var arr2Map = makeIndexMap(arr2);


console.log(arrMap["Mary"]);
console.log(arr2Map["Josh"]);
```

---

**Edit:** a performance test

```js
var myTestData = createTestData();
var randomNameToFind = (function() {
  var namesToFind = ["Aileen","Christina","Donna","Judith","Mandy","Sandra","Dawn","Tracey","Mhairi","Victoria","Carolyn","Gayle","Maria","Valerie"];
  
  return function() {
    return namesToFind[Math.floor(Math.random() * namesToFind.length)];
  }
}());

console.log("Finding the number index for a random name out of 800 names, 10000 times:");

console.time("using index of approach");

var usingIndexOf = (a,n) => a.findIndex(e => e[1].indexOf(n) !== -1);
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
  results.push(usingIndexOf(myTestData, randomNameToFind()));
}
console.timeEnd("using index of approach");

console.time("using map approach");

var makeIndexMap = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(map, data, index) {
    data[1].forEach(function(key) {
      map[key] = index;
    });

    return map;
  }, {});
};
var myMap = makeIndexMap(myTestData);
results = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j += 1) {
  results.push(myMap[randomNameToFind()]);
}
console.timeEnd("using map approach");
console.log("index map size: " + sizeof(myMap) + " bytes");


              

// Random data generation code below
function createTestData() {
  var names = ["Nicola","Karen","Fiona","Susan","Claire","Sharon","Angela","Gillian","Julie","Michelle","Jacqueline","Amanda","Tracy","Louise","Jennifer","Alison","Sarah","Donna","Caroline","Elaine","Lynn","Margaret","Elizabeth","Lesley","Deborah","Pauline","Lorraine","Laura","Lisa","Tracey","Carol","Linda","Lorna","Catherine","Wendy","Lynne","Yvonne","Pamela","Kirsty","Jane","Emma","Joanne","Heather","Suzanne","Anne","Diane","Helen","Victoria","Dawn","Mary","Samantha","Marie","Kerry","Ann","Hazel","Christine","Gail","Andrea","Clare","Sandra","Shona","Kathleen","Paula","Shirley","Denise","Melanie","Patricia","Audrey","Ruth","Jill","Lee","Leigh","Catriona","Rachel","Morag","Kirsten","Kirsteen","Katrina","Joanna","Lynsey","Cheryl","Debbie","Maureen","Janet","Aileen","Arlene","Zoe","Lindsay","Stephanie","Judith","Mandy","Jillian","Mhairi","Barbara","Carolyn","Gayle","Maria","Valerie","Christina","Marion","Nicola","Karen","Susan","Claire","Fiona","Angela","Sharon","Gillian","Julie","Jennifer","Michelle","Louise","Lisa","Amanda","Donna","Tracy","Alison","Elaine","Jacqueline","Sarah","Caroline","Elizabeth","Laura","Lynn","Deborah","Lesley","Margaret","Joanne","Pauline","Lorraine","Carol","Kirsty","Yvonne","Lorna","Emma","Lynne","Tracey","Heather","Catherine","Pamela","Helen","Linda","Jane","Anne","Kerry","Suzanne","Wendy","Victoria","Diane","Mary","Dawn","Clare","Gail","Paula","Ann","Shona","Hazel","Christine","Andrea","Samantha","Marie","Lynsey","Sandra","Denise","Lee","Kelly","Gayle","Debbie","Jill","Kathleen","Patricia","Joanna","Catriona","Shirley","Ruth","Zoe","Leigh","Rachel","Melanie","Kirsteen","Aileen","Christina","Janet","Katrina","Stephanie","Audrey","Kirsten","Arlene","Maureen","Morag","Marion","Mhairi","Allison","Cheryl","Maria","Kim","Anna","Lindsay","Rebecca","Katherine","Mandy","Nicola","Karen","Claire","Angela","Fiona","Susan","Jennifer","Julie","Gillian","Michelle","Sharon","Sarah","Louise","Donna","Laura","Amanda","Alison","Lisa","Caroline","Kirsty","Jacqueline","Elaine","Lesley","Lynn","Deborah","Elizabeth","Joanne","Emma","Tracy","Lorraine","Lynne","Margaret","Heather","Carol","Lorna","Pauline","Kelly","Helen","Catherine","Linda","Victoria","Suzanne","Kerry","Pamela","Lee","Wendy","Jane","Yvonne","Tracey","Anne","Clare","Mary","Diane","Christine","Lynsey","Samantha","Shona","Andrea","Marie","Gail","Melanie","Dawn","Ann","Paula","Jill","Ruth","Leigh","Hazel","Debbie","Joanna","Denise","Lindsay","Gayle","Patricia","Catriona","Kathleen","Sandra","Leanne","Stephanie","Rachel","Katrina","Shirley","Kirsteen","Janet","Arlene","Zoe","Jillian","Anna","Judith","Mhairi","Natalie","Audrey","Carolyn","Morag","Aileen","Cheryl","Rebecca","Allison","Barbara","Mandy","Claire","Nicola","Karen","Angela","Gillian","Fiona","Jennifer","Laura","Susan","Julie","Michelle","Lisa","Sharon","Louise","Sarah","Tracy","Donna","Kelly","Kirsty","Amanda","Alison","Joanne","Caroline","Emma","Jacqueline","Elaine","Elizabeth","Lynne","Lesley","Deborah","Kerry","Victoria","Carol","Catherine","Lynn","Pauline","Margaret","Lorna","Lynsey","Lorraine","Linda","Suzanne","Tracey","Heather","Yvonne","Jane","Dawn","Mary","Helen","Anne","Wendy","Lee","Pamela","Jill","Lindsay","Clare","Christine","Diane","Leigh","Samantha","Shona","Joanna","Ruth","Debbie","Gail","Marie","Andrea","Paula","Kathleen","Catriona","Katrina","Denise","Melanie","Ann","Sandra","Gayle","Hazel","Jillian","Stephanie","Rachel","Kim","Natalie","Katherine","Patricia","Leanne","Cheryl","Mhairi","Morag","Arlene","Zoe","Kathryn","Aileen","Ashley","Judith","Anna","Frances","Janet","Lucy","Vicky","Christina","Kirsten","Rebecca","Nicola","Claire","Laura","Karen","Michelle","Louise","Jennifer","Fiona","Lisa","Gillian","Angela","Julie","Susan","Sarah","Kelly","Donna","Sharon","Emma","Caroline","Alison","Joanne","Tracy","Kirsty","Lynne","Amanda","Elaine","Jacqueline","Lesley","Kerry","Elizabeth","Lynn","Margaret","Deborah","Catherine","Heather","Lorna","Yvonne","Carol","Lorraine","Suzanne","Lynsey","Victoria","Helen","Linda","Pauline","Dawn","Anne","Jane","Tracey","Clare","Mary","Diane","Jill","Denise","Lee","Leanne","Christine","Shona","Pamela","Samantha","Paula","Joanna","Debbie","Stacey","Hazel","Cheryl","Lindsay","Gail","Rachel","Marie","Ann","Catriona","Andrea","Ruth","Kathryn","Katrina","Mhairi","Wendy","Leigh","Gayle","Melanie","Sandra","Stephanie","Anna","Jillian","Amy","Carolyn","Patricia","Carrie","Natalie","Kathleen","Lyndsey","Ashley","Rebecca","Vicky","Christina","Lindsey","Katherine","Arlene","Sara","Laura","Claire","Nicola","Lisa","Louise","Michelle","Fiona","Karen","Gillian","Jennifer","Emma","Angela","Susan","Kelly","Julie","Donna","Sarah","Kirsty","Sharon","Joanne","Amanda","Tracy","Alison","Elizabeth","Caroline","Elaine","Jacqueline","Lynne","Leanne","Deborah","Lesley","Lorraine","Victoria","Lynn","Pamela","Kerry","Lynsey","Lorna","Carol","Margaret","Heather","Helen","Catherine","Suzanne","Tracey","Yvonne","Cheryl","Linda","Pauline","Debbie","Jane","Dawn","Clare","Lindsay","Mary","Shona","Anne","Rachel","Jill","Christine","Natalie","Samantha","Diane","Lee","Wendy","Joanna","Paula","Marie","Ann","Denise","Catriona","Gayle","Hazel","Kathleen","Stacey","Gail","Ashley","Andrea","Ruth","Anna","Jillian","Leigh","Katrina","Stephanie","Mhairi","Katherine","Sandra","Lyndsey","Christina","Lucy","Patricia","Carrie","Rebecca","Kathryn","Lyndsay","Melanie","Amy","Sara","Arlene","Kirsten","Laura","Claire","Lisa","Nicola","Louise","Karen","Fiona","Jennifer","Michelle","Emma","Sarah","Gillian","Kelly","Susan","Angela","Donna","Kirsty","Julie","Pamela","Joanne","Caroline","Amanda","Tracy","Sharon","Lynne","Elaine","Deborah","Jacqueline","Alison","Lynsey","Victoria","Kerry","Leanne","Lorraine","Lesley","Elizabeth","Lorna","Catherine","Lynn","Suzanne","Heather","Helen","Lindsay","Margaret","Clare","Cheryl","Debbie","Pauline","Dawn","Carol","Mary","Natalie","Linda","Jane","Diane","Stacey","Carrie","Yvonne","Rebecca","Christine","Marie","Charlene","Rachel","Anne","Tracey","Jill","Samantha","Ashley","Paula","Joanna","Stephanie","Andrea","Shona","Denise","Anna","Hazel","Katrina","Ruth","Gayle","Lee","Sara","Catriona","Kathryn","Leigh","Mhairi","Wendy","Amy","Jillian","Katherine","Gail","Linsey","Christina","Lucy","Melanie","Sandra","Ann","Kathleen","Shelley","Kirsten","Kim","Lyndsey","Laura","Claire","Lisa","Nicola","Emma","Louise","Jennifer","Michelle","Sarah","Fiona","Karen","Gillian","Kirsty","Donna","Kelly","Pamela","Susan","Julie","Angela","Amanda","Lynsey","Sharon","Lynne","Deborah","Joanne","Victoria","Caroline","Alison","Leanne","Gemma","Elaine","Jacqueline","Lesley","Elizabeth","Lorraine","Kerry","Heather","Debbie","Catherine","Lynn","Lorna","Tracy","Suzanne","Yvonne","Cheryl","Natalie","Margaret","Lindsay","Diane","Helen","Pauline","Ashley","Rachel","Clare","Carol","Christine","Linda","Dawn","Rebecca","Stephanie","Jill","Tracey","Jane","Stacey","Paula","Shona","Anna","Charlene","Anne","Marie","Catriona","Samantha","Joanna","Ruth","Andrea","Mary","Denise","Kim","Mhairi","Hazel","Lauren","Amy","Kathryn","Carrie","Lyndsey","Lucy","Gail","Katherine","Christina","Linsey","Wendy","Katrina","Kimberley","Ann","Lee"];
  var nameMap = names.reduce((map, n) => {
    map[n[0]] = map[n[0]] || [];
    map[n[0]].push(n);
    return map;
  }, {});

  var testData = Object.keys(nameMap)
    .sort()
    .reduce((res, k) => {
      res.push([k, nameMap[k]]);
      return res;
    }, []);

  return testData;
};
```

```html
<script src="http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/finding-the-memory-usage-of-objects/sizeof.compressed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this eat more memory if I have 500+ values?

Comment: I can't imagine 500 items being a problem.

Comment: I included a speed comparison and map size. List of 800 names, retrieve 1 random name 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [["present",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["absent",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];

var arr2 = [["J",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["M",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];

arr.forEach(function(e,i,a){
  if(e[1].indexOf("Mary")>-1){
    console.log(e[0])
  }
});

arr2.forEach(function(e,i,a){
  if(e[1].indexOf("Josh")>-1){
    console.log(e[0])
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First using filter() and second findIndex()

```
var arr = [["present",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["absent",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];
var result1 = arr.filter(x => x[1].indexOf("Mary") !== -1)[0][0];
console.log(result1); // absent
var arr2 = [["J",["John","Josh","Jay"]],["M",["May","Mary","Mary Jane"]]];
var result2 = arr.findIndex(x => x[1].indexOf("Josh") !== -1);
console.log(result2); // 0
```